# Use props inside button with onclick event

Tags: reactjs, onclick

I need help, I'm make a application, in mi app need that press the button and redirect to other external page, I know this onclick function its easy

```
onClick={event =>  window.location.href='/your-href'}
```

My problem is that I need to use props to select an external page, I need this to be dynamic, I thought of using `onClick={event => window.location.href='{props.url'}` obviously doesn't work, how to do?

well I say, I thought of using `onClick={event => window.location.href='{props.url'}` obviously doesn't work, how to do? can someone help me??

Comment: What's framework you use? React?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: thanks everyone for your feedback, i was able to figure it out using this <a href={props.link}><Button>{t("jobCard.modalbtn2")}</Button></a>